# Font issue after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: fonts, windows-10-upgrade, parallels

I have just upgraded my Parallels VM to Windows 10 (previously 8.1).

After the upgrade, I noticed that some fonts are not being honoured by Report Builder 3.0 (the SQL Server power-user report authoring tool). They are *selectable from the fonts dialog*, but seem just to be ignored (and are rendered in Arial without any warnings).

Affected are 3 <s>custom</s> non-standard fonts (OTFs, which I had purchased from foundries and installed some months ago, and which were working fine prior to the Win 10 upgrade), only one of which now renders correctly. Thinking it might be OTF related, I sourced the TTF for one of these, but the TTF version exhibits the same behaviour (selectable, but renders in Arial) in Report Builder.

The fonts seem to be working correctly in Word. Seems like this might be specific to Report Builder.

Are there some recommended diagnostic steps? Have I missed something?

Comment: For the time being, I've reverted back to Windows 8.1. Upon doing so, I am not experiencing these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Some incorrectly written fonts will map over other fonts, like Arial.ttf. This has not been a problem until Windows 10 and the changes made with DirectWrite.

FIX:
If you are in Windows 10, there are no fonts older than 1/26/2012 installed by default. Find all fonts older than this date, and delete them while Chrome or any other application with font problems is open. The font causing the problem (taking over Arial.ttf) will not be able to be deleted until Chrome, etc. is closed. Restore the fonts you just deleted except for the font that wouldn't let you delete it. If the problem is still not solved, try again. I was able to fix my pc, and many others using this method, and this method only, other than a clean install with no additional fonts installed afterwards.